# Oracle SQL Missing Keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to display the most popular product (format_id) in a given month (JAN-14) and group them by a count of each format_id.

Here is my Query :

```
select PRODUCT, AMOUNT
from (Select Order_108681091.Order_Date, order_line_108681091.Format_id as Product,   
COUNT(*) AS AMOUNT FROM order_line_108681091 
Inner Join order_108681091
On order_108681091.order_id = order_line_108681091.order_id
Where order_108681091.Order_Date like '%JAN-14%'
group by Format_id
order by AMOUNT desc);
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: `INNER JOIN` requires a condition

Comment: The inner join from the table to another without an on clause seems unusual (cartesian effect), but I also suspect order_date is a date data type and not a string, so the like clause there is not going to work either.

Comment: select PRODUCT, AMOUNT
    from (Select Order_108681091.Order_Date,    order_line_108681091.Format_id as Product, COUNT(*) AS AMOUNT FROM order_line_108681091 
Inner Join order_108681091
ON order_108681091.order_id = order_line_108681091.order_id
Where order_108681091.Order_Date like '%JAN-14%'
group by Format_id
order by AMOUNT desc);

Comment: Sorry... the above won't let me format. I have a condition in it of ON  order_108681091.order_id = order_line_108681091.order_id but it throws a "not a group expression". I'm just learning this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You said you have the condition, so let's start with adding it.
2. There is no need to `ORDER BY`, so remove it.
3. Remove `Order_date` from the subquery `SELECT`
4. Use aliases
5. The subquery itself would be enough.

```
SELECT l.Format_id as PRODUCT,   
       COUNT(*) AS AMOUNT 
  FROM order_line_108681091 l
       INNER JOIN order_108681091 o
           ON o.order_id = l.order_id
 WHERE o.Order_Date LIKE '%JAN-14%'
GROUP BY 
       l.Format_id;
```

Comment: Thanks man! The original one works but the update throws an "unknown identifier" exception. You've been a huge help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the inner join:

```
inner join order_108681091 ON order_1078681091.ID = order_line_018681091.ID
```

or something like that.  Also your where clause probably wont work unless you're storing that date as a string and not a datetime datatype.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the subquery at all.  And, I'm very uncomfortable using `like` on a date directly.  Explicitly convert the date to a string:

```
select ol.Format_id as Product, COUNT(*) AS AMOUNT 
from order_line_108681091 ol Inner Join
     order_108681091 o
     ON o.order_id = ol.order_id
where to_char(o.Order_Date, 'MMM-YYYY') = 'JAN-2014'
group by ol.Format_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

Actually, if you have in index on `OrderDate`, you can use the following (to take advantage of the index):

```
select ol.Format_id as Product, COUNT(*) AS AMOUNT 
from order_line_108681091 ol Inner Join
     order_108681091 o
     ON o.order_id = ol.order_id
where o.Order_Date >= to_date('2014-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and
      o.Order_Date < to_date('2014-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
group by ol.Format_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

Moving the function from the column to the constant allows the use of an index on the column.